# Show rgb numpy array in matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have numpy array:

```
>> print(data[0].shape)
(3, 5, 5)
```

which corresponds to `5x5` RGB image. When I try `plt.imshow(data[0])` I get `TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data`. How to properly show this image?

Comment: Try plotting `data.swapaxes(0,2)` or `data.transpose(1,2,0)`.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a 3 dimensional matrix, not a 5x5 image. 
A 5x5 RGB image would appears like this:

`a1 a2 a3 a4 a5
b1 b2 b3 b4 b5
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
d1 d2 d3 d4 d5
e1 e2 e3 e4 e5`

What you are showing, is 3 dimensions matrix, in which the 3rd dimension does not correspond to any volume (as in 3d images) either. Hence the `invalid dimensions` error. What you want to do is to incorporate into an n * m  matrix the RGB numbers you want to display, such that X_{r:j}=RGB. Then you can display the matrix as an image.

Example of image matrices:

```
from numpy.random import rand
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow

img = rand(5, 5)  # Creating a 5x5 matrix of random numbers.

# Use bilinear interpolation (or it is displayed as bicubic by default).
imshow(img, interpolation="nearest")  
show()
```

Displays:

[image: 5x5 image]

Of course the numbers in this matrix do not correspond to RGB colours, but intensity, and are displayed through the default `colourmap` (Jet). But I'm sure you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is with the order of your axis.

As Divakar commented, you can swap your axes first and the you can use OpenCV to show it on a window instead of using MPL which will show you the real colors.

```
import cv2
data = data.swapaxes(0,2)
cv2.imshow('image',data)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

However, if you want to use a MPL with colormap as Xenatisch proposed, you can change your matrix from RGB to Grayscale with OpenCV and then use `imshow`

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data = data.swapaxes(0,2)
gray_data = cv2.cvtColor(data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # from (5x5x3) to (5x5) matrix, perfect for plotting!
plt.imshow(gray_data, cmap = 'gray', interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

You can use any other colormap that you want. Take into account that I assume that your depth colors are on BGR format. If they are in another order, roll or make the required changes ;)

On all cases the swap axes is required as the order should be (height,width,depth), and you have (depth,height,width)